# Same input that gives different output?

Tags: c++, recursion, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm trying to code a function that takes a boolean equation as its input, and gives the answer of the equation as its output. For example:

> Input: (!T|T)&F

> Output: F

However, in some scenarios, (when there are parentheses, the same input would sometimes give True, sometimes False). For example:

> Input: (T|T)&T

sometimes gives T, sometimes F. I'm new at programming, and I'm not sure I understand how memory works exactly, can someone please check my code and explain what's happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

bool boolFunc(char* input, long len){
    // Base cases
    if(len == 2 && *input == '!'){
        if(*(input+1) == 'T') return false;
        if(*(input+1) == 'F') return true;
    }
        
    else if(len == 1){
        if(*input == 'T')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    //
    else{
        for (long i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            //for equations with '(' and ')'
            if(*(input + i) == ')'){
                for (long j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if(*(input + j) == '('){
                        if(*(input + j - 1) == '&')
                            return boolFunc(input, j-1) && boolFunc(input+j+1, i-j-1);
                        else
                            return boolFunc(input, j-1) || boolFunc(input+j+1, i-j-1);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(*(input + i) == '&'){
                return boolFunc(input, i) && boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i-1);
            }
            if(*(input + i) == '|'){
                return boolFunc(input, i) || boolFunc(input+i+1, len-i-1);
            }
            
        }
    }
    return false;
}


int main(){
    
    char input[500] = {'\0'};
    cin.getline(input, 500);
    if(boolFunc(input,strlen(input)))
        cout << "T" << endl;
    else
        cout << "F" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiling with `-fsanitize=address` gives me a loud memory error (including line numbers) for your troublesome input. Start with that and use the debugger along with the sanitizer output to figure out what state the program is in and how it got there, or whether that state is valid and you forgot to handle it.

Comment: ok thanks! I'm using Xcode, and am not really familiar with the debugging process, do you have any recommendation of tutorials I could watch?

Comment: I haven't used Xcode personally, but it should come with gdb or lldb integrated into an easier-to-use UI. However, the basic debugging tools of setting breakpoints, stepping through the code, checking the values of things, and navigating the callstack will get you quite far in debugging general problems. Xcode is going to have some way of doing each of those, but I imagine any sort of Xcode debugging reference material will show how.